# 'lock' seems not to work correctly in custom synchronized collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm using the following code to create an SynchronizationRoot for my synchronized collection:

*TSynchronizedArray.cs*

```
public object SynchronizationRoot
{
    get
    {
        if(this._SynchronizationRoot == null)
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange<object>(ref this._SynchronizationRoot, new object(), null);
        }

        return this._SynchronizationRoot;
    }
}
```

which is pretty similar to the implementation of the .NET standard collections.

The next code snippet is what I use for adding items to the collection and clearing it (where `this._Items` = `T[]`):

*TSynchronizedArray.cs*

```
public void Add(T Element)
{ 
    lock(SynchronizationRoot)
    {
        if (this._Count == this._Items.Length && !this.IsFixedSize)
        {
            if(this.Capacity <(this._Count + 1))
            {
                int NewCapacity = this.Capacity * 2;
                Capacity = NewCapacity;
            }
        }

        this._Items[this._Count++] = item;
    }
}

public void Clear()
{
    lock(SynchronizationRoot)
    {
        Array.Clear(this._Items, 0, this._Count);
        this._Count = 0;
        this._SerializationInfo = null;
    }
}
```

Ignore the `_SerializationInfo`, I think it's not relevant at this point, it's just for the implementation of `ISerializable`.

So now to the **example**:

*Progam.cs*

```
TSynchronizedArray<int> Array = new TSynchronizedArray<int>();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
        Parallel.For(0, 12, (i) => {
            Array.Add(1024 + i);

            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                Array.Clear();
            }
        });
    }));

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
        Parallel.For(0, 12, (i) => {
            Array.Add(2024 + i);
        });
    }));

    Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
        Parallel.For(0, 12, (i) => {
            Array.Add(3024 + i);
        });
    }));

    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
    t3.Start();

    while (t1.IsAlive || t2.IsAlive || t3.IsAlive) ;

    for (int i = 0; i < Array.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Array[i]);
    }
```

***Output***

```
1035
2024
2025
2026
2028
2029
2030
2031
2032
2033
2034
2035
```

Where are the 3k+ Items ? and sometimes the collection even contains just a couple of items like 2 or 3.

Why? as far as I know I'm using the lock correctly and if I do the exact same example using an `System.Collections.ArrayList` it works fine.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do here, or what you were expecting. It seems entirely feasible due to random scheduling that `thread3` has completed all of its work completely before `thread1`, say, executes the iteration with an `i` value of `10` and clears the array.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever since it should be an synchronized collection the first thread I schedule should completely finished when the next one fires up and so on.. so I was expecting an result like: `thread1` : 1035; `thread2` : 2024 - 2035, `thread3` : 3024 - 3035 (at least this is what the `System.Collections.ArrayList` is outputting). Or do I have an completely wrong understanding of how 'lock' should work?

Comment: You're locking *individual* method calls on the collection. Imagine you have no overhead due to `Thread` or `Parallel.For` startup and you just have 36 tasks all trying to call `Add` - there's no guarantee which of them will succeed first. But we're fairly sure that when that task leaves the `Add` call, one of the others is probably already waiting to enter the lock and does. But 6 of your tasks (the even numbered ones launched by thread 1), *subsequently* call `Clear` which requires a *separate* entry into the lock. Chances are high many other tasks have already completed by then.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so is my initial implementation of the locking mechanism wrong or is it just an rubbish example? should I consider not locking individual method calls or consider splitting up locks for individual methods? and one question is left over: why does it work on `System.Collections.ArrayList` (synchronized) ?

Comment: Standard problem with threading, the class itself it perfectly thread-safe.  But the client code is not, thread-safety is not a transitive property.  Exactly which thread will call Clear() last and when is entirely random.  So what content remains is entirely random.  You perhaps hope that code in t2 and t3 runs after the code in t1 but the synchronization that is required to ensure this is missing.  Microsoft made the same kind of mistake with the ArrayList.Synchronized() method.  The returned object is not in fact thread-safe for iteration.

Comment: Both @Damien_The_Unbeliever and @Hans Passant, thanks for commenting and finally helping me a bit out here, so but what would be an appropriate soulution here in order to make it more comfortable for the client? using `Monitor` and checking in some sort of global thread pool if the Id of the previous thread is still present?

Comment: I'd difficult to know what an appropriate solution would be because the current usage seems far too abstract from whatever real world problem you're trying to solve. All we know is that you apparently have 36 tasks that all want to add something to a collection and that 6 of those tasks also, apparently, want to clear the collection. We don't know the relationships between those tasks, what useful work they're actually doing, why 6 of them are "special", etc.